# SVG in Chart does not Re-render after props Change. React + d3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg

Trying to create a simple bar chart using d3.js . I have also gone ahead and provided a button to create random data to be used as the dataset for the svg bar chart. However, the bars in svg only render for the first dataset. Even though i change the values for datasets, the bar chart remains the same. Help needed.

I checked the props to see if they were changing. the props were updating, but wasn't changing the bars in the chart.

App.js file :

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state={
        dataSet: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
      }
  }

  dataSetCreator = () =>{
    let n = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
    this.setState({
      dataSet : [...Array(n)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*10))
    })
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.dataSet)
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <div className="d3-chart">
         <span>Bar Chart With D3</span>
       <BarChart  
        data={this.state.dataSet}
        height={500}
        width={500}/>
        <button onClick={()=>this.dataSetCreator()}>Change Data</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

BarChart.js:

```
class BarChart extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.createBarChart();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.createBarChart();
    }

    createBarChart = ()=>{
        const svgWidth = this.props.width
        const svgHeight = this.props.height;

        var svg = d3.select('svg')
                .attr('width', svgWidth)
                .attr('height', svgHeight)
                .attr('class', 'bar-chart');
        debugger
        var dataset = this.props.data;
        var barPadding = 5;
        var barWidth = (svgWidth / dataset.length);

       svg.selectAll('rect')
                       .data(dataset)
                       .enter()
                       .append('rect')
                       .attr('y', (d)=>svgHeight-(d*5))
                       .attr('height', (d)=>d*5)
                       .attr('width', barWidth-barPadding)
                       .attr('transform', (d, i)=>{
                           var translate = [barWidth*i, 0];
                           return "translate(" + translate + ")"
                       })


    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.data)
        return(
            <svg>

            </svg>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the [general update pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54109605/5385381) in `createBarChart`

```
createBarChart = () => {

    const svgWidth = this.props.width
    const svgHeight = this.props.height;

    var svg = d3.select('svg')
      .attr('width', svgWidth)
      .attr('height', svgHeight)
      .attr('class', 'bar-chart');

    var dataset = this.props.data;
    var barPadding = 5;
    var barWidth = (svgWidth / dataset.length);

    var rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(dataset)

    var rectsEnter = rects.enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('y', (d) => svgHeight - (d * 5))
      .attr('height', (d) => d * 5)
      .attr('width', barWidth - barPadding)
      .attr('transform', (d, i) => {
        var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
        return "translate(" + translate + ")"
      })

    rects.attr('y', (d) => svgHeight - (d * 5))
      .attr('height', (d) => d * 5)
      .attr('width', barWidth - barPadding)
      .attr('transform', (d, i) => {
        var translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
        return "translate(" + translate + ")"
      })
    rects.exit().remove();
  }
```

Also I had a problem with Array.map not working on `[...Array(n)]` in stackblitz so had to change `dataSetCreator` (I'm not sure if this applies to your environment).

```
  dataSetCreator = () => {
    let n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    let newData = Array.from({ length: n }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 39));
    this.setState({
      dataSet: newData
    })
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t5nvkz)

Comment: Thank you, Works like a charm!